# Change a state param and not reload the state. Feasible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI-Router v1.0rc1, is it possible to transition to the current state, changing only one param, without reloading the state. Let me give you my use case:

On the left of the page I show the listings titles of a user. When clicking on a title the main content is changed to... the listing data obviously. When clicking on another title, the current 'listing' state is reloaded and fed with other data. In my listing template, I have a map. Each time a new listing must be displayed, the dom is destroyed and reloaded (with the same template) which kills the map and rebuilds it. I would prefer to only change the params (the listing id) of the listing state, detect it and change the content of the template (and reposition the map). The actual listing data is currently loaded in the resolves thanks to the id param.

Is it something feasible?

Comment: transition state using $state.go or transationTo and ```notify:false```

Comment: notify seems deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$state.go('some.state', { param: 'x' }, {reload: false});
```

more about `reload` can be found [here](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.transitionoptions.html#reload)

Comment: Could not make it work. By reading the doc, it's more as if the purpose of the param was to force a reload when there is normally none. In the meantine, I found the "dynamic" keyword for a state param and I'm trying that.